# Whats the best way to handle thousands of URL redirects in IIS

Tags: php, iis, drupal-7, iis-8

My company is in the process of rebuilding our site.  The URL structure is going to drastically change which means we will be setting up quite a few redirects..1000's in fact.

We are going to be using IIS 8 and PHP (Drupal 7) and I am wondering what is the best way to handle all of these?  What are the limits?  And how much of a speed degradation could this possibly cause?

Thanks in advance

Comment: many options: perhaps if you have the info, redirect all old to a single page that does a db lookup and redirects to the new (output appropriate headers also). just one approach, we really don't know enough about your particulars ho advise you on the best approach

Comment: What other particulars are needed here? In IIS I can enter these in the web.config file but that would get pretty large. Woudl using the URL rewrite extension be best?  Possibly doing this in a db table for all pages not found before they hit a 404 might end up being the best answer.  Im just looking for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Use Drupal and the redirect module

I have no experience of hosting Drupal on an IIS server though so I cant say what the performance penalties are.